# Pandas issue with removing NaNs from df and then creating a dict

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using pandas to get data from an URL and add it to a dataframe. It works but the df does have some NaNs in it which is causing me some problems. When I try to replace the NaNs with fillna(0) I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'fillna'
```

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Factions_(Skyrim)'
df = pd.read_html(url)
df = df.fillna(0)
skyrim_data = (df[0].to_dict(orient='records'))
```

Answer (score 3):

`read_html()` does not returning a dataframe, it returns a list of dataframes instead because in one html there could be more than 1 tables. So if you just want the first table, you have to specify first which dataframe on the list you want to `fillna()`, then you can make it to dict.

```py
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Factions_(Skyrim)'
df_list = pd.read_html(url)
df = df_list[0].fillna(0)
skyrim_data = (df.to_dict(orient='records'))
```